# How do you delete all spaces that is 2 char long or more in vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to delete every double space in a file open in vim, how is this done?

e.g delete space here

```
a  a
```

but keep the space here

```
a a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:%s/\s\{2,}//g`

Where the elements are:

- `%s` substitute in the whole file
- `\s` what to substitute: a space
- `\{2,}` two or more occurrences
- `//` replace with nothing (i.e. delete)
- `g` do it on every occurrence on the current line (not only on the first)

The elements shall become clearer if you look at the [anatomy of the substitute call](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3as):

```
s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS
```

So, the `PATTERN` in our case is `\s\{2,}`, the `REPLACEMENT` is empty and `FLAGS` are just `g`. The range gets prefixed and is `%` which indicates the whole file. If you just want to do it on some lines, you could select the lines visually and then type `:s....`

---

**Edit:**
In your question, you wrote that you want to

> delete every double space in a file

That's what I answered. If you want to replace two and more spaces by one, the command would be

```
:%s/\s\{2,}/ /g
```

Comment: Just to be clear about a minor point: The `\s` pattern doesn't match "a space" but rather whitespace in general. In Vim, the pattern given would match a combination of two or more instances of  <Space> and <Tab>.

Answer (score 0):

How about this `:%s/  */ /g`

(there are two spaces in between `/` and `*`)

Comment: There should be three spaces and if you but the desired keystrokes on its own line, it will format correctly (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
:%s/\s\s\+/ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer with `{` is most efficient, I find it easier to remember the space `*` solution.  The correct solution would include three spaces (because `*` matches 0 or more).

```
:%s/   */ /g
```

Of course, this also assumes you want to replace two **or more** spaces with a single space.